# How to configure matlab toolbox when I use c# both?

Tags: c#, matlab, configure

I'm trying to use the Neural Network of matlab in c#.I have compiled the code to .Net Assembly then I call the matlab functions in c# ,and then I got the Exception:

**... MWMCR::EvaluateFunction error ... 
Error using nnetParamInfo (line 28)
FCN is not the name of a function on the MATLAB path.**

the exception throwed at the line that I simply create a network:

**net = elmannet();**

So, I think this problem is due to the wrong path configuration of toolbox.
I tried to issue path command in Matlab and got a long list of toolbox and other things.

How can I solve this problem?

Any help will be appreicated !!

Comment: In addition,I have call some simple function sucessfully..If I try to call a function in toolbox,I will get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Not all of Neural Network Toolbox is supported by the deployment products, including MATLAB Builder for .NET. See the [Compiler Support](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html) page for details. In particular, you can only deploy functions that apply pre-trained networks - you can't deploy the functions that create or train new ones.